# Evitar que se generen procesos o subprocesos de excel mediante un programa en C#

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en C# el cual lee de un archivo de Excel, este programa tiene implementado un timer en donde cada cierto tiempo obtiene los datos de la celda, los muestra en una interfaz de Windows Form y los envia a una BD SQL, mi preguntas es como evitar que se generen subprocesos de Excel cuando esta corriendo mi porgrama.

Inserte una referencia para poder leer el archivo de Excel en C# la cual es

```
Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library
```

codigo

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
       try{
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range;
        //MisVariables
        DatosGetSet datos = new DatosGetSet();
        double modulo = 0, numLlanta = 0, timeConstruccion = 0, timeCiclo = 0, codigoBarras = 0;
        String operador = null, codigoLlanta = null;
        String codBarAux = null, sqldate = null, sqltime = null;
        //VariablesParaManipularElExcel
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        //InstanciasNecesariasParaQueAbraYTrabajeConElExcelYELDataPlcSheet
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\NX00612\Desktop\modulos.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); //Obtiene que hoja trabajar segun el debug
                                                                          //EmpiezaAContarElTotalDeColYFilas
        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
        row = range.Rows.Count;
        column = range.Columns.Count;
        //R,C ExtraigoLosValoresDeCadaCelda
        sqldate = DateTime.Now.ToString("d-MM-yyyy");
        sqltime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm");
        modulo = (range.Cells[40, 2] as Excel.Range).Value;
        operador = (range.Cells[40, 3] as Excel.Range).Value;
        codigoLlanta = (range.Cells[40, 4] as Excel.Range).Value;

        txtFecha.Text = sqldate + " " + sqltime;
        datos.fechaA = sqldate;
        datos.horaA = sqltime;
        txtModulo.Text = modulo.ToString();
        datos.moduloA = modulo.ToString();
        txtOperador.Text = operador.ToString();
        datos.operadorA = operador.ToString();
        txtCodLlanta.Text = codigoLlanta.ToString();
        datos.codeLlantaA = codigoLlanta.ToString();

        //EsAquiCuandoInsertoEnBDSiEsDiferenteA
        if (!codigoBarras.Equals(codBarAux))
        {
            DatosDAL.Agregar(datos);
            codBarAux = codigoBarras.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Dato repetido");
        }
        //UsoElObjetoParaQueCierre
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
        xlApp.Quit();
        //ParaQueFinaliceLosObjetos
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
       }
       catch (Exception ex){
        MessageBox.Show("Se produjo un error al leer el archivo de excel \n Error: " + ex.Message, "FATAL ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Coloca todo el código para reproducir tu escenario, caso contrario estamos tratando de adivinar cuál podría ser la causa, revisa este enlace: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: tienes que liberar con dispose() lo que utilices de excel para eviatar dejar procesos en uso, por ejemplo xlApp.Dispose();